# Have a derived table with records filtered by property of base table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-core, single-table-inheritance

In my case, I have two classes.
One base class and one derived class.
This is my base class:

```
public class A
{
   public long Id {get; set;}
   public bool Condition {get; set;}
}
```

and here is  my derived class:

```
public class B : A
{
   public bool ConditionB {get; set;}
}
```

but what i want to do is to have one table with different classes in entity framework in a way that the base table's records move between tables as the properties change etc.
something like :

```
public class B :A where (condition for B)
{
  public bool IsShipped {get;set;}
}
```

where C is

```
  public class C:B where (c is Bs with IsShipped)
   {

   }
```

I don't know how to do this.
Is this even possible?

Comment: derived classes don't make different tables. They create one table for all derived with an additional field that stores the type (A, B or C)

Comment: The additional column is called `discriminator` and you should be able to manually assign its value.

Comment: A) thats one approach but thers also TPT (table per type) and B)the point of the question is really weather or not conditional inheritance is a thing